# GPX file gets incorrect buffer QGIS

Tags: qgis, buffer, gpx

When I try to perform a buffer of 10m on my imported gpxfile (geometry listed as points), the buffer covers more like 1000 km. I tried the same with a line vector file, which seems to work properly. I had no problem importing the GPX file into QGIS.

I've checked if the CRS was the same as the project's and
I've looked for a alternative way of transforming the gpx into a shapefile, which I didn't find.

I only have this data as an gpx file, and I really need to use it! I am a QGIS-beginner, so I hope it is an easy fix?

Comment: Rightclick you GPX-layer and save it using a fitting UTM/projected CRS and as a shapefile. Currently it seems to be in a geographic CRS, thus the buffer is created using degrees as distance unit.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I am afraid I am not doing it right, because I still do not get the option for m. I right click the file>export>save as. format: ESRI Shapefile. File name: CT_location. CRS: I have tried EPSG:5467- Panama-Colon 1911 (my points are in Panama), I also tried EPSG:4326 - WGS 84, EPSG:4328 - WGS 94 (geocentric)(deprecated). Then I would save it. load the new shapefile, try the buffer and only see degrees.

Comment: Have you tried https://epsg.io/32617 or https://epsg.io/32618? Unlike 5467 (https://epsg.io/5467) these have UoM (unit of measurement) `m` instead of `degree`. So, you simply chose the wrong alternate CRS. QGIS 3.x actually has a large warning sign when you try to buffer a layer using degree for units.

Comment: You're right that worked! Thank you!